# How to replace %20 with - in Url Rewriting

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am using [UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter.dll](http://www.urlrewriting.net) for url rewriting purpose and frankly, I am new to this stuff. My problem is that , i want to replace %20 in my url with -.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a custom replace apart that HttpUtility gives you (in this case it will convert it to space!) then just use string replacement.

```
Uri myuri = new Uri(myolduri.ToString().Replace("%20","-"));
```

Comment: Wrap this transformation into a helper method and use it for binding.

Answer (score 5):

[HttpUtility.UrlDecode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode.aspx) does what you need.

Comment: If i am right then in my aspx page , you want to say this <%#string.Format(~/Mypage/{0},HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Eval("MyNamewithSpaces")))%> .... is it???????????

Comment: That would turn %20 into a space.  The questioner is trying to turn them into - (dash).

Answer (score 0):

or you can put the url in a string then use

```
string urla = "your url";
string urlb = url.Replace("%20", "-");
```